# Wordpress "permalinks" under the hood

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, permalinks

this may be too general question to ask, but how does wordpress permalink work?

clearly they dont work with htacces only what it seems?!

there is that page where a "[template tree](https://developer.wordpress.org/files/2014/10/Screenshot-2019-01-23-00.20.04.png)" is listed

"single.php"-url is like that: "https://example.com/thisisanarticle"
"page.php"-url is like that: "https://example.com/apage"

so how does wordpress know what to call? both urls share the same structure after all.

Answer (score 0):

Under the hood, WordPress uses their [`WP_Rewrite`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_rewrite/) mechanism to create/update entries in Apache's `.htaccess` file whenever permalinks are added/removed/updated.

The [class](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/class-wp-rewrite.php) and [its implementation in the WordPress core](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/rewrite.php) use a set of rules to query the WordPress database and write the rules into `.htaccess` each time an update is determined to be required.